# ES6 import gives Unexpected Identifier SyntaxError when running on terminal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, export, command-line-interface

I am new to the whole ES6 concept and I am currently trying to use the `export` and `import` modules. I have a simple code that just `log`s something to the `console`. Below are the codes

**autoincrementId.js**

```
export default function autoincrementId() {
  return 'hey';
}
```

**log.js**

```
import autoincrementId from '../helpers/autoincrementId.js';

console.log(autoincrementId());
```

When I run my code with `node` on the terminal, I get this error
[image: screenshot of the error]

The `autoinrementId` stands as the `printOut` in the error
When I use the `module.exports` and `require` everything works fine. But I want to use the `export` `import`. I have already set up my environment using instructions from https://babeljs.io/setup#installation

Please, how do I fix this cause all answers have read on SO tells me to add a `type="module"` when in `HTML` but I am running on the terminal? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @epascarello fixed that and edited the question but that wasn't the issue;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Node.js, run the script with the [`--experimental-modules`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) flag. This will allow you to use ES modules in Node.js without the need to transpile the import/export statements.

```
node --experimental-modules ./path/to/your.js
```

The error is sort of misleading because without this flag, Node is trying to parse your script as a CommonJS module instead of an ES module, which does not understand `import`/`export`.

Comment: @WhiteHox what version of Node are you using? Can you do a `node -v`?

Comment: @WhiteHox No update is required. The flag should be supported in that version.  How are you running the script? What command are you using? I expect it to be something like `node --experimental-modules log.mjs`.

Comment: Yea @joseph but must they be in the same directory?

Comment: Oh! and it has to be `.mjs` extension?

Comment: @WhiteHox See the linked article. It's either `.mjs`, or  defined `type: "module"` in the nearest `package.json` if you want to remain using `.js` (I believe the latter is only on v12, not sure).

Comment: Thanks. it worked when I changed the extension but one more thing. I don't think i am allowed or rather sopposed to push an `.mjs` file to production am i?

Comment: @WhiteHox I would not recommend pushing anything under an experimental flag to production (some platforms won't let you set flags, so you can't even use this). However, this feature is scheduled to be [unflagged once v12 hits LTS status](https://medium.com/@nodejs/announcing-a-new-experimental-modules-1be8d2d6c2ff).