# nodejs: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]

I'm taking a look at https://github.com/intoli/remote-browser. I'm working in win10 with node 11.5. I've followed the instructions at the bottom of the repo:

```
# Clone the repository.
git clone https://github.com/intoli/remote-browser.git
cd remote-browser

# Install the dependencies.
yarn install

# Build the project.
yarn build

# Run the tests.
yarn test
```

Now when I try to run it using :

```
$ node src/index.js
E:\ENVS\js\remote-browser\src\index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Browser from './browser';
                                                                    ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:267:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:319:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:684:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:342:17)
```

How can I get this working?

edit index.js:

```
import Browser from './browser';
import ConnectionProxy from './connections/proxy';

export default Browser;
export { Browser };
export { ConnectionProxy };
export * from './errors';
export * from './launchers';
```

edit2:

```
{
  "name": "remote-browser",
  "version": "0.0.15",
  "description": "A low-level browser automation framework built on top of the Web Extensions API standard. ",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:intoli/remote-browser.git",
  "author": "Intoli, LLC <contact@intoli.com>",
  "license": "BSD",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "Set NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack",
    "build:web": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/web-client.config.js",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "test": "npm run build && NODE_ENV=test mocha --exit --require babel-core/register",
    "test-fast": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --exit --require babel-core/register --invert --grep Browser",
    "watch": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --watch --config webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend": "^1.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.17",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^4.11.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "jimp": "^0.2.28",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.0",
    "webextension-polyfill": "^0.2.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-chrome-extension-reloader": "^0.6.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^2.37.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-ws": "^3.0.0",
    "geckodriver": "^1.11.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
    "simple-websocket": "^5.1.0",
    "ws": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 import gives Unexpected Identifier SyntaxError when running on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56279455/es6-import-gives-unexpected-identifier-syntaxerror-when-running-on-terminal)

Comment: Maybe showing us that `vm.js` file and especially lines around 83 would be fine

Comment: You can't do an `import` statement inside a function.

Comment: Doesn't Node support `import` yet? How come implementing this standard ES6 feature take such a long time?

Comment: @JeremyThille Node *does* support it, but in any environment `import` must be at the global (module) level, not inside of a function.

Comment: Indeed, I missed this point

Comment: @Pointy,  I'm not knowledgeable about node, but is the code in a function here? - I've added the entire provided index.js file created by the repo owner.

Comment: @user61629 ah OK, that's just Node being weird. Well in that case the problem is that you have to be explicit with Node (in one of a few different ways) to tell it that a source file is a module. [See this documentation.](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules)

Comment: I just realized yarn build did not work - please see answer below . I'll have to investigate this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run `node src/index.js`. When you run `yarn build` it will create a new folder `dist` in the root folder, which has all the source code. Go to this folder and find the `index.js` file, open this to learn more.

Comment: Thanks Tran, didn't know that. I've added the package.json file above, but I am not seeing dist in the root directory, so something is wrong and I guess the build did not happen.

Comment: You can go here [https://github.com/intoli/remote-browser/blob/master/webpack/client.config.js](https://github.com/intoli/remote-browser/blob/master/webpack/client.config.js) to view how to project build. It has an `output` that have `path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'dist'),`. This means it will build source to `dist` file. To learn more, please learning [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to learn how this build your source.